# Import python project modules from tests subdirectory

Tags: python, import

```
├── ledger
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── ledger_data.py
│   └── ledger_model.py
├── main.py
├── sscommon
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── logging.py
└── tests
    └── test_ledger_data.py
```

I need to import classes from `ledger_data` module when running `test_ledger_data.py`. I currently do `sys.path.append("../")` in `test_ledger_data.py` or I have to add symbolik links to all modules being used to `tests` directory. Both options seem incorrect. How to do it correctly?

If I just run the file either from project root or `tests` directories I get error:

```
    from ledger.ledger_data import LedgerData
ImportError: No module named 'ledger'
```

Comment: create a `__init__.py` file inside `tests/` folder and put your inputs there

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `__init__.py` file in your folder, and import the parent dir using:

```
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir))
sys.append(parent_dir)
```

This uses `os.path` to find out the directory based on your file location.

---

**Update**: create the above `__init__.py` and reside it inside `tests/` folder.
Then, in your `test_ledge_data.py` put at the head of the file `from __init__ import *`; this will import everything in your init file to your module namespace.

Comment: Please clarify how do you mean to use tests then? If I run directly (as in original question) `python3 test_ledger_data.py` your code is not imported/run. If I run from a new python file residing in root dir it works even without this code.

Comment: Is it anything better than `sys.path.append("../")` ? I've read here on SO that it isn't a good practice. Will not it have side effects when doing `from tests.test_ledger_data import TestLedgerData`, if eventually I decide to run from some other location?

Comment: @VladimirLenin The code above imports the parent folder; so as long as the structure is kept even if you move it to some other location - it would work. If you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting and accepting it, thanks